# Why my code runs to infinite loop when I enter a non-integer input?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

Why I'm having an infinite loop when I enter a non-digit token?

```
public class ExceptionHandling {
    static int i;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        boolean b=true;
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        while (b ==true) { 
            try{
                i=in.nextInt();
                b=false;
                // System.out.println("not executrd bcoz above exception");
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e){      
                System.out.println(i);
            }     
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: thats fine because u entering integer if u enter non integer exception should be there but it is going in finite loop after that.

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne  now check the question

Comment: thanks Maroun Maroun

Answer (score 2):

You're actually asking "why my code runs to infinite loop when I enter a non-integer input".

Well, you need to call `in.next()` in the `catch` clause to solve this. Why? See the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) docs:

> When a scanner throws an `InputMismatchException`, the scanner **will not pass the token** that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved or skipped via some other method.

Comment: tahnks man somebody understood

Comment: is there any other solution.

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary Yes, you can reinitialize the scanner object in the `catch` clause: `in = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: I think the problem is of extra tab that is after entering digits when we press Enter nextLine() read  that and don't asks for input.

Comment: @ArjunChaudhary tabs has nothing to do with Java. You can add 100000 tab, Java doesn't care. I already explained what's the problem.